# fixing logic in Removing duplicates from linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to remove duplicates from linked list, but I have a bug in the code, I can't figure it out... So it seems there is a logical bug when for example found a duplicated node, the deletion is not correct?

```
ListNode *deleteDuplicates(ListNode *head) {

    if (head == nullptr)
        return head;

    bool visited[255];

    memset(visited, false, sizeof(visited));

    ListNode * t = head;
    ListNode *p = head;
    while (t)
    {
        if (!visited[t->val])
        {
            visited[t->val] = true;
        }
        else{
            ListNode *temp = t;
            p->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;

        }
        p = t;
        t = t->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you find a duplicate you delete temp which actually equals to t. Then later, when you call `t = t->next` you're referring to a deleted pointer which is of course illegal.

A simple solution would be to change the while loop to look like:

```
while (t)
{
    ListNode *temp = NULL;     // added
    if (!visited[t->val])
    {
        visited[t->val] = true;
    }
    else{
        temp = t;              // changed
        p->next = temp->next;
        // delete temp;        // commented out (moved below)
    }
    p = t;
    t = t->next;

    if (temp) {                // Added - delete temp folder in case it was set
        delete temp;          
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes undefined behavior. When you delete the object pointed by `temp`, it disqualifies the internal fields of the object, including the `next` field. Since `t` points to the same object as `temp`, `t`'s fields also become invalid. Therefore, the assignment `t = t->next` will produce non-deterministic result.